# OAuth2 Spring authentication works but not in the correct way

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Im stuck with this for the past 2 weeks and google is not helping. (i dont know how to ask the proper questions to get the answers i need)

**Questions in short are:**

**---------------**

1) Can someone explain to me how I enable the resource server to use the database for authenication instead of in memory.

I tried: editing OAuth2Config.java: method configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) to use the database but itdoesn't create keys or anything but the authentication still works.....

2) Also can someone explain how I can use Postman/curl/(something else) to check if authentication works properly.

Explained below

3) Also if I made mistakes in my code or maby I do things the wrong way? please explain to me what and why im doing it the wrong way. I want to learn from my mistakes.

**---------------**

I have to say im new to spring and oauth. So my knowledge is minimal (im also a graduating student)

Im using Java(Netbeans 8.2) with Maven and Spring to create a Webshop. im responible for the API (authentication and resource management)

What i need in the end is a working WebshopAPI that i can make calls to. The webshop itself is hosted somewhere else, so i only need the api to authenticate and return a JSON with, for example, products.

I used [this](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html) as documentation/guide

[Link to bitbucket repo](https://bitbucket.org/hunteroooox/oauth2_webshop_school)

At the moment im stuck with testing if the authentication works. when i run the application and goto: **localhost:8080/getallproducts**, i get a login screen. 
Username: user, Password: [string from console]. i get products back. Now when i open postman, i goto the same address and user oauth2 to get a key. i still get the login screen instead of a key... and i don't know how i can change it to use client/secret instead of username/password.

If i missed any information feel free to ask.

Also if have been looking for proper oauth2 starting point. every post i find about the subject does everything in a diffrent way, why is there not a standard!!! I find this very frustrating/annoying/stressfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! if you look in the git now, you see some changes. i found out that the authentication server did not start when i ran the application. now i moved the resource and authentocation server to the main run class and everything started working. with thanks to @JohanB

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to setup the authorization server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource); // table = oauth_access_token
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource); // table = oauth_client_details
    }
}
```

Don't forget to populate the oauth_client_details table.

Resource server looks good.

I assume that you want to use the authorization code flow?

Postman

1. add authoriation to a request by clicking on the Auth tab underneath the request url.
2. type is OAuth2.0
3. "Get New Access Token"

Fill in:

- Grant type is "Authorization Code"
- Callback URL "https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback" -> set in oauth_client_details
- Auth URL "http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize"
- Access Token URL "http://localhost:8080/oauth/token"
- Client ID, secret, scope -> use from oauth_client_details table
- Client Authentication ".. in body"

Postman will redirect you to the user confirmation page.

After approval postman will recieve a Request token, add it to request header.
Now you should be able to access the resource server endpoints.

Comment: i did as you said. The weird thing is: when i fill everything in in postman where you say i have to insert it, and click on get key i get a login page... why am i getting that?? but when i login with username: user, password: from console. it opens a window like this https://imgur.com/a/Yd8mH. it doesn't return a key... am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: When requesting a token using the Authorization_code flow, the user needs to approve the code grant. This means that the user is redirected to an authorization server page where he needs to identify. If you don not configure user authentication, spring will create a default user and password.

Comment: Alright, i didn't know that. How do I configure user authentication? And why is my DB not filled with keys? it does not create keys, yet in the console it successfully authenicates users.... Do you know why that could be?

Comment: Do you fully understand the OAuth2 Authorization_code flow? There is a third party application that wants to consume your api (credentials in oauth_client_details) in the name of one of your users. The third pary application is only allowed to preform requests in name of your user *after* he approves this. In order for your user to approve this, he needs to be able to authenticate to your application. Your users can come from a database, ldap, preauthentication, active directory, etc. _User keys/tokens are only generated after user approval._

Comment: Yes I do know the flow. I know that the webshop(client) can only access a resource (in my case products from DB) when it has been approved. But i havn't found an example online that worked in my usecase. does oauth allow me to "skip" this step? Not skip but do it in the background, so the user does not see the login screen?

Comment: Here is a diffrent question: why is my application not filling my DB with the tokens it got?

Comment: The correct flow: redirect user to login screen. Let user approve the third party application. The user will be redirected to the third party app after approval wil an authorization code. This code can be exchanged by the third party app for a token. The token generation is the last step. If you do not fix the previous steps in the flow, no tokens will be generated.